# mysql best backup method? and how to dump backup to target directory

Tags: mysql, database-backups

What is the best method to do a MySQl backup with compression?  Also, how do you dump that to specific directory such a C:\targetdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `mysqldump` command will output CREATE TABLE and INSERT commands that are sufficient to recreate your whole database. You can back up individual tables or databases with this command.

  You can easily compress this. If you want it to be compressed as it goes, you will need some sort of streaming tool for the command line. On UNIX it would be `mysqldump ... | gzip`. On Windows, you will have to find a tool that works with pipes.

  **This I think is what you are looking for.** I will list other options just because.
- `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` will flush all data to the disk and lock them from changing which you can do while you are making a copy of the data folder.

  Keep in mind, when doing restores, if you want to preserve the full capability of MySQL bin logs, you will not want to restore parts of a database by touching the files directly. Best option is to have an alternate data dir with restored files and dump from there, then feed to your production database using regular mysql connection channels. Any direct changes to the filesystem will not be recorded by binlogs.

  If you restore the whole database using files, you will be OK. Just not if you to peices.

  `mysqldump` does not have this problem
- **Replication** will allow you to back up to another instance of MySQL running on the same or different machine.
- binlogs. Given a static copy of a database, you can use these to move it forward in time. binlogs are a log of all the commands that ever changed the data. If you have binlogs back to day one, then you may already have what you are looking for. You can run all the commands from the binlogs from day one to any date you wish and then you have a copy of the database from that date.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/). It's a GPL licensed alternative to MySQL's paid Enterprise Backup tool and can create consistent non-blocking backups from databases even when they are written to. See [this article](http://vitobotta.com/painless-hot-backups-mysql-live-databases-percona-xtrabackup/) for more information on why you'd want to use this over mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script like [AutoMySQLBackup](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mysqlscript.htm), which automatically does a backup every day, keeping daily, weekly and monthly backups, keeping your backup directory pretty clean and uncluttered, while still providing you a long history of backups.

The backups are also compressed, naturally.

Comment: does AutoMySQLBackup support linux?

Comment: @Mike: It is probably mainly targetting linux, so yes.